# Generator instead of list comprehension? And where else can I improve my class?

Tags: python, class, generator, list-comprehension

I'm rather new to Python. Lately I was looking into the python's concept of classes. Well, for a couple of scripts I wrote I thought it would be handy to define a class which puts together a SQL-statement (in ArcGis dialect). Nothing fancy really. Here is what I came up with. I'm asking two things: first, general flaws? Suggestions for improvement? Secondly, I'm a little stuck with the code of the last function `def constructor`. Actually I want to return the tuple from the dictionary and not a list. But the list comprehension is nice. So what about a generator? I can't figure exactly out how to do that...

```
class ArcSql:
    type_book = {'str':("'","'"), 'int':("", "")}
    format_book = dict(shp=("'","'"), GDB=("[","]"))

    def __init__(self,colom_name, values_list, value_type = 'str', arc_format ='shp'):
        self.colom = colom_name
        self.values = values_list
        self.valtype = self.constructor(type_book, value_type)
        self.aformat = self.constructor(format_book, arc_format)
        self.colom_formated = str(self.aformat[0][0]) + self.colom + str(self.aformat[0][1])

    def statement(self):
        temp_state = []
        connector = "'OR' "
        count_values = len(self.values)
        if count_values == 0:
            return("error, not enough values...")
        else:
            for v in self.values:
                x = self.colom_formated + " = " + str(self.valtype[0][0]) + v + str(self.valtype[0][1]) + ' ' + connector
                temp_state.append(str(x))
        state = "".join(temp_state)[:-5]              
        return(str(state))

    def constructor(self, book, book_key):
        return([v for k,v in book.iteritems() if k==book_key])
```

Comment: By way of improvements: You could tidy up the `colom_formated` line a bit by using string substitution: `"%s%s%s" % (self.aformat[0][0], self.colom, self.aformat[0][1])`, which is faster too. The same goes for the `x = ...` line. 
Comparing `if count_values == 0:` isn't very pythonic - `boolean([])` are equal to `False`, so `if not self.values` will do the job. All the calls to `str()` are overkill too - you're already working with strings, no need to convert them again.

Comment: `return` is a keyword and not a function (think: how would such a function be implemented?), and thus the parentheses around the thing to return are unnecessary (and fairly widely considered ugly). Also, it's spelled *column*, assuming you mean the counterpart to a row.

Comment: Thanks mate, very useful suggestions. Even though I personally don't really like the string substitution - I think it makes the code harder to read. But that might have to do with my coding experience or better said, it's lack. Anyways, thanks for your help, it is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first question should be better asked in the [codereview site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Regarding your second question, you could use a generator as follows:

```
def constructor(self, book, book_key):
    for k, v in book.iteritems():
        if k==book_Key:
            yield v

...

for value in obj.constructor(book ,book_key):
    # Do whatever you need with value
```

Anyway, my understanding is that you're going to get only one result from the list comprehension, in such a case:

```
def constructor(self, book, book_key):
    return next(v for k, v in book.iteritems() if k==book_key, None)

...

value = obj.constructor(book ,book_key)
if value is not None:
    # Do whatever you need with value
```

Where [`next`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) is a built-in to return the next value of an iterator or the default value passed (`None` in this case) if the iterator is exhausted (if no default value is passed, an exception will be raised in that case).

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the fast answer, you guys are of great help! Well, I don't really get the `None`-part. Is that a substitute for v? To help you with error handling?

Comment: Yes, if no default value is defined and there isn't any value that satisfies `k==book_key`, then a `StopIteration` exception will be raised. Otherwise (if a default value is defined) the default value will be defined. Whether you prefer the exception or the default value depends on the problem and the code you're working on.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily change your list comprehension into a generator, just by swapping the `[]` for `()`, to make it a generator, and swapping `return` for the generator keyword `yield`:

```
yield (k,v in book.iteritems() if k==book_key)
```

That should now return only one tuple - if you want more (as a list), you'll need to call `list(constructor())`.

Comment: this is what I tried. But `self.valtype` becomes a generator object and I can't get my head around how to access the tuple...

Comment: @larsvegas Ah, then call `next()` on the generator, as in jcollado's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def constructor(self, book, book_key):
    return([v for k,v in book.iteritems() if k==book_key])
```

If `book` is a dictionary, its keys are unique. So why iterating over this dict to find the value?

Why not:

```
def constructor(self, book, book_key):
    return (book[book_key],)
```